# Bytes Command Function Not Working for PySerial

Tags: python, pyserial

I have a function which takes a set of values and converts it into a bytes string. For example, I need:

```
input_array = ['E9', '01','06','57','4A','01','F4','01','01','EF']
## needs to become b'\xE9\x01\x06\x57\x4A\x01\xF4\x01\x01\xEF'
```

The function I have is:

```
def string_to_command(inp): 
    new_string = ''
    for i in inp:
        new_string += r'\x' + i
    return new_string.encode('latin-1')
```

When I print both commands:

```
print(string_to_command(input_array))
print(b'\xE9\x01\x06\x57\x4A\x01\xF4\x01\x01\xEF')
# OUTPUT b'\\xE9\\x01\\x06\\x57\\x4A\\x01\\xF4\\x01\\x01\\xEF'
# OUTPUT b'\xe9\x01\x06WJ\x01\xf4\x01\x01\xef'
```

I am not sure what is going on here. The last one with b"" actually commands my output device properly, the other does not. How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert to int first, then to bytes.

```
>>> a = ['E9', '01','06','57','4A','01','F4','01','01','EF']
>>> bytes(int(x, base=16) for x in a)
b'\xe9\x01\x06WJ\x01\xf4\x01\x01\xef'
```

Answer (score 2):

> The last one with b"" actually commands my output device properly, the other does not. How do I fix this problem?

I think what is going on here is that you are trying to add \x to every value and then encoding it from there. The problem with that is `'E9'` and `\x'E9'` are not the same:

```py
>>> 'E9'.encode()
b'E9'
>>> '\xE9'.encode()
b'\xc3\xa9' <-- Not the same
>>>
```

One method I like is [`bytes.fromhex(s)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.fromhex), where `s` is your 'hex string'.

```py
input_array = ['E9', '01','06','57','4A','01','F4','01','01','EF']

# use "".join(input_array) to get all values combined
# into one string
res = bytes.fromhex( "".join(input_array) )
```

**Outputs** :
`b'\xe9\x01\x06WJ\x01\xf4\x01\x01\xef'`

Answer (score 1):

You can join a list of bytes converted from the original array with `latin-1` encoding. So adding `\x` as join sequence, it will output the desired bytes object:

```
input_array = ['E9', '01','06','57','4A','01','F4','01','01','EF']

print(b''.join([bytes.fromhex(x) for x in input_array]))
```

**Output:**

```
b'\xe9\x01\x06WJ\x01\xf4\x01\x01\xef'
```

Comment: @SunderamDubey then you don't understand the question. this answer specifically creates the output that is **not working** for OP, as they stated in the question. and it's doing convoluted acrobatics to do the thing it does

Comment: @christoph-rackwitz You're right, I was generating the wrong output. I have edited the question so it now creates the right bytes value

Comment: and that's still *needlessly inefficient* (N calls to bytes.fromhex on the inside, instead of just one on the outside) because you are trying to not literally copy the top answer's code. for someone who applies big-O notation to many questions, I'm surprised you aren't doing that here as well.

Comment: @christoph-rackwitz I know it's inefficient with a list comprehension, but it works for small-sized inputs like this one.